# i want to append 1 div element after i submit(don't use action) then all value of form should display on another page (Answer is only in plain js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the Html Code

```html
<div class="form-group" id="divFectchAllQuestion">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-correct" name="checkCheckbox"  onclick="addRightAnswer();">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your option"class="form-control-range-number1" id="get-radio-input1" name="get-radio-input" value="">
    <input type="number" class="get-radio-input-number" value="0" name="get-radio-input"/>
    <button type="click" onclick="addMoreOptions(this)">
       <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" disabled>
       <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you please answer it @sergeykuznetsov

Comment: can you please answer it @clod9353